# Ubuntu 16.04 HDMI audio stopped working (shows as unplugged but works in tty1)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio, hdmi

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 and connecting to an Onkyo receiver w/ HDMI for sound. Initially everything worked fine and I was able to select HDMI output from ***Settings > Sound > Output***. Something happened and now I no longer see the HDMI option in ***Settings > Sound > Output*** and when viewing the pulse audio volume control all HDMI options are listed as unplugged.

I was able to test on a tv and everything works fine so it is not the cable. It is also not the receiver since if I go to tty1 terminal w/ ***ctr + alt + f1*** with hdmi sound selected, the sound suddenly appears as expected. When I switch back to GUI w/ ***ctr + alt + f7*** the sound is muted again.

Things I've tried

1. pulseaudio -k
2. check alsamixer for muted channels (everything shows 00)
3. messed around w/ "pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo" command combinations
4. manually deleted .config/pulseaudio files
5. Diables pulse audio via

   mkdir ~/.pulse

   echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf

   pulseaudio -k

[Missing HDMI audio output option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQjHZ.png)

[HDMI unplugged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEKWb.png)

[alsamixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHqd1.png)

pacmd -list-cards output

```
2 card(s) available.
index: 0
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 6
properties:
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI at 0xb2610000 irq 50"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:03.0"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "0a0c"
    device.product.name = "Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "0"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5200, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5200, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5200, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5200, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: unknown)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo-extra1>
sinks:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo-extra1/#2: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
sources:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor/#3: Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
ports:
    hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
index: 1
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 7
properties:
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xb2614000 irq 49"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "9c20"
    device.product.name = "8 Series HD Audio Controller"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "1"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: unknown)
    output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
    output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
sinks:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#1: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
sources:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor/#1: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#2: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
ports:
    analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
    analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
```

aplay -l output

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3239 Analog [ALC3239 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I appreciate any and all attempts to help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the operating system fixed the issue.